# Lighting/material issues when creating a collada model and importing to three.js scene

Tags: materials, collada, three.js

I'm working in blender to create collada (dae) models which are then imported into a three.js urban scene created by the [qgis2threejs](https://github.com/minorua/Qgis2threejs) plug-in for qgis (open-source GIS software).

I am driving myself crazy trying to match the colors of the collada models and objects rendered by three.js. The following image is an example of this:

[image]

In this image are four collada models, set amid a number of polygons created and skinned in three.js. closest to the fore (white) is a model that has no materials attached to it.

Second beyond that (dark red) is a model that has materials attached to it similar to this: 
[image]

To the left of that is a two-tone model in which I attempted to match the two-tones of the polygons: 
[image]

The blue/grey building is a similar build, but with emitting ramped to around 30 under the material/shading tab.

None of these were exported with light sources attached (which I realize is probably the issue). The reason I am not including light sources is because that when I do, the new light source washes-out the polygons created by the plugin.

However, why does the unskinned material appear fine, but the others do not? Further, the scene has a built-in light source, why is that not illuminating the materials in a similar manner to the polygons?

And finally, is there a way to export the models with materials to match the polgyons created by three.js? - this is what I'm really after.

Sorry, blender noob.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: Okay, so what I'm trying to do isn't really possible then, or rather should be attempted within the three.js rendering environment if I read that correctly. Good to know I'm not insane.

Comment: Might be worth trying [glTF-Blender-Exporter](https://github.com/khronosgroup/gltf-blender-exporter) and `THREE.GLTFLoader`. Or consider baking lights and using a shadeless material.